# What is nautilus-desktop - CPU hungry process [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, cpu, overheating

for a few days I was having overheating problems with my laptop and i realized that my CPU was constantly oscillating around 30%. When checking with `top` I noticed a process called `nautilus-desktop` was running and using a lot of CPU so I killed it and everything is now back to normal (I still need to check reboot though).

Does any one knows what `nautilus-desktop` is and what it is used for ??
thanks

Comment: Here I have a problem with Skype. For some unknown reason, every once and a while my CPU gets at 100%. With ```htop``` I see that the hungry process is ```nautilus-desktop```.  But, the problem is solved when I close Skype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subsidiary process of the Nautilus file manager, added in v. 3.2.2. Don't worry, every once in a while it happens to the best of packages.  It's rare this happens, so you need not uninstall it, just kill it if it gets hungry again.

Comment: How do I start the process again after terminating it? All my desktop icons are gone. Running `nautilus-desktop` in a terminal gets them back but I can't close the terminal without killing that process. `nohup` works but that seems like a dirty solution, is there a better way?